# How to get the content of an HTML table cell?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td id='A1'>2011-11-01</td>
   <td id='B1'>John</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How can I get the content of the cell A1 using Javascript?

Comment: You are not familiar with DOM properties. If you were familiar then you yourself would have found the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use document.getElementById('A1').innerHTML

Comment: +1: It's only a matter of time, though, before the jQuery villagers start chasing you with pitchforks and torches.